# Need some help with customization of ERC-20 smart contract

Tags: solidity

I’m new here and with Ethereum. I'm trying to run a presale using an ERC-20 smart contract. It's a smart contract that I downloaded from Github.
Developer however is probably very busy or non-responsive.

I want to do a presale and want the following addresses hard coded in the smart contract:
The contract address of the token.
The address of the token holder.
The address of the fund receiver.

This is what I did:

```
XToken NewToken;

bool public is_preselling;
address payable owner = payable(0x6F................8Gf);
address payable tokenSource = payable(0xF40.............788); 
address payable fundreceiver = payable(0xAd9.......14D5);
uint256 soldTokens;
uint256 receivedFunds;
```

Here’s the full smart contract.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^ 0.8.0;

interface XToken {
    function totalSupply() external view returns(uint256);
    function balanceOf(address account) external view returns(uint256);
    function transferFrom(address sender, address recipient, uint256 amount) external returns(bool);
    function transfer(address recipient, uint256 amount) external returns(bool);

}

contract SaleController{
    event TokenPurchased(address indexed _owner, uint256 _amount, uint256 _bnb);
    event ClaimedToken(address indexed _owner, uint256 _stakeId, uint256 _date);

    XToken NewToken;

    bool public is_preselling;
    address payable owner = payable(0x6F................8Gf);
    address payable tokenSource = payable(0xF40.............788); 
    address payable fundreceiver = payable(0xAd9.......14D5);
    uint256 soldTokens;
    uint256 receivedFunds;


    struct tokenVesting{
        uint256 amount;        
        uint256 date_added;     
        uint256 redeem_date;    
        uint256 redeem_count;
    }
    
    uint256 redemptionCount = 1; //1 times to redeem means one time release
    uint256 lockDays = 30; //1 month duration every redemption (total of 30 days or 1 month)
    uint256 rewardRate = 5; //5% reward for vesting the tokens

    uint256 public RecordId;
    mapping(uint256 => tokenVesting) idVesting; 
    mapping(uint256 => address) recordIdOwner;   

    constructor(XToken _tokenAddress)  {
        Token = _tokenAddress;
        owner = payable(msg.sender);
        fundreceiver = owner;
        is_preselling = true;
    }

    modifier onlyOwner() {
        require(msg.sender == owner, "invalid owner");
        _;
    }
    
    //buy tokens
    function tokensale(uint256 _amount ) public payable returns(bool)  {
        require(is_preselling, "pre selling is over.");

        uint256 _rewardAmount = (_amount * rewardRate) / 100; //get total reward for vesting
        uint256 _totalTokens = _amount + _rewardAmount; //total totens (principal + reward)

        RecordId += 1; //auto increment for every record

        //save new vesting record
        tokenVesting storage _vesting = idVesting[RecordId];
        _vesting.amount = _totalTokens;
        _vesting.date_added = block.timestamp;
        _vesting.redeem_date = block.timestamp + (lockDays * 1 days); //set 1st redemption date (+30 days)

        //track down the owner of the record id
        recordIdOwner[RecordId] = msg.sender;

        //transfer tokens to contract address
        Token.transferFrom(tokenSource, address(this), _totalTokens);

        //transfer bnb or network native coin
        fundreceiver.transfer(msg.value);
        
        soldTokens += _amount;
        receivedFunds += msg.value;

        emit TokenPurchased(msg.sender, _amount, msg.value);
        return true;
    }

    function Redeem(uint256 _id) public returns(bool)  {
        
        //verify the owner of the stake record
        address _recordOwner = recordIdOwner[_id];
        require(_recordOwner == msg.sender, "invalid owner");

        tokenVesting storage _vesting = idVesting[_id];

        //validate if total redemption is not greater than 4 or (redemption count)
        require(_vesting.redeem_count < redemptionCount, "already redeemed");
        
        //validate if redemption date is ready
        uint256 _redeemDate = _vesting.redeem_date;  
        require(block.timestamp >= _redeemDate, "not yet ready to redeem");

        uint256 _redeemAmount = _vesting.amount / redemptionCount; //amount every redemption (divided by number of redemption or 4)

        _vesting.redeem_count += 1; //update count of redemption max of 4
        _vesting.redeem_date = block.timestamp + (lockDays * 1 days); // update date for next redemption +30 days 

        //tokens will be transferred to user's wallet address
        Token.transfer(msg.sender, _redeemAmount);

        emit ClaimedToken(msg.sender, _id, block.timestamp);
        return true;
    }
    
    function getTokenSupply() public view returns(uint256){
        return Token.totalSupply();
    }
    
    function getTokenbalance(address _address) public view returns(uint256){
        return Token.balanceOf(_address);
    }
    
    function totalSoldTokens() public view returns(uint256){
        return soldTokens;
    }
    function totalReceivedFunds() public view returns(uint256){
        return receivedFunds;
    }
    
    function getbalance()  public onlyOwner {
        owner.transfer(address(this).balance);
    }

    
    function SetReceiver(address payable _fund) public onlyOwner {
        fundreceiver = _fund;
    }


    function SetPreSellingStatus() public onlyOwner {
        if (is_preselling) {
            is_preselling = false;
        } else {
            is_preselling = true;
        }
    }

}
```

Do I need to make more changes to make it work? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If we're looking at the constructor logic, we can see that the `owner` address will be set at the deployment time together with the `fundreceiver` address:

```
constructor(XToken _tokenAddress)  {
    Token = _tokenAddress;
    owner = payable(msg.sender);
    fundreceiver = owner;
    is_preselling = true;
}
```

Thus, there's no reason to hardcode these values, because they will be overridden. What I would to in your case would be to add a dedicated method for updating the owner:

```
function setOwner(address payable _owner) public onlyOwner {
    tokenSource = _tokenSource;
}
```

So, the actual steps that you need to do are:

- deploy the smart contract
- update the `owner` by calling the `setOwner()` method
- update the `fundreceiver` by calling the `SetReceiver` method

Other than that, you can keep the same logic for setting the `tokenSource` address, but it can be a good idea to create a dedicated method for updating the `tokenSource` address too, if there're any changes in the future:

```
function setTokenSource(address payable _tokenSource) public onlyOwner {
    owner = _owner;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

.. {

// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^ 0.8.0;

interface XToken {
function totalSupply() external view returns(uint256);
function balanceOf(address account) external view returns(uint256);
function transferFrom(address sender, address recipient, uint256 amount) external returns(bool);
function transfer(address recipient, uint256 amount) external returns(bool);

}

contract SaleController{
event TokenPurchased(address indexed _owner, uint256 _amount, uint256 _bnb);
event ClaimedToken(address indexed _owner, uint256 _stakeId, uint256 _date);

```
XToken Token;

bool public is_preselling;
address payable owner;
address payable tokenSource; 
address payable fundreceiver;
uint256 soldTokens;
uint256 receivedFunds;


struct tokenVesting{
    uint256 amount;        
    uint256 date_added;     
    uint256 redeem_date;    
    uint256 redeem_count;
}

uint256 redemptionCount = 1; //1 times to redeem
uint256 lockDays = 30; //1 month duration every redemption (total of 30 days or 1 month)
uint256 rewardRate = 5; //5% reward for vesting the tokens

uint256 public RecordId;
mapping(uint256 => tokenVesting) idVesting; 
mapping(uint256 => address) recordIdOwner;   

constructor(XToken _tokenAddress) {
    Token = _tokenAddress;
    owner = payable(_tokenAddress);
    tokenSource = payable(0xF40.............788);
    fundreceiver = payable(0xAd9.......14D5);

    is_preselling = true;
}

modifier onlyOwner() {
    require(msg.sender == owner, "invalid owner");
    _;
}

//buy tokens
function tokensale(uint256 _amount ) public payable returns(bool)  {
    require(is_preselling, "pre selling is over.");

    uint256 _rewardAmount = (_amount * rewardRate) / 100; //get total reward for vesting
    uint256 _totalTokens = _amount + _rewardAmount; //total totens (principal + reward)

    RecordId += 1; //auto increment for every record

    //save new vesting record
    tokenVesting storage _vesting = idVesting[RecordId];
    _vesting.amount = _totalTokens;
    _vesting.date_added = block.timestamp;
    _vesting.redeem_date = block.timestamp + (lockDays * 1 days); //set 1st redemption date (+30 days)

    //track down the owner of the record id
    recordIdOwner[RecordId] = msg.sender;

    //transfer tokens to contract address
    Token.transferFrom(tokenSource, address(this), _totalTokens);

    //transfer bnb or network native coin
    fundreceiver.transfer(msg.value);
    
    soldTokens += _amount;
    receivedFunds += msg.value;

    emit TokenPurchased(msg.sender, _amount, msg.value);
    return true;
}

function Redeem(uint256 _id) public returns(bool)  {
    
    //verify the owner of the stake record
    address _recordOwner = recordIdOwner[_id];
    require(_recordOwner == msg.sender, "invalid owner");

    tokenVesting storage _vesting = idVesting[_id];

    //validate if total redemption is not greater than 4 or (redemption count)
    require(_vesting.redeem_count < redemptionCount, "already redeemed");
    
    //validate if redemption date is ready
    uint256 _redeemDate = _vesting.redeem_date;  
    require(block.timestamp >= _redeemDate, "not yet ready to redeem");

    uint256 _redeemAmount = _vesting.amount / redemptionCount; //amount every redemption (divided by number of redemption or 4)

    _vesting.redeem_count += 1; //update count of redemption max of 4
    _vesting.redeem_date = block.timestamp + (lockDays * 1 days); // update date for next redemption +30 days 

    //tokens will be transferred to user's wallet address
    Token.transfer(msg.sender, _redeemAmount);

    emit ClaimedToken(msg.sender, _id, block.timestamp);
    return true;
}

function getTokenSupply() public view returns(uint256){
    return Token.totalSupply();
}

function getTokenbalance(address _address) public view returns(uint256){
    return Token.balanceOf(_address);
}

function totalSoldTokens() public view returns(uint256){
    return soldTokens;
}
function totalReceivedFunds() public view returns(uint256){
    return receivedFunds;
}

function getbalance()  public onlyOwner {
    owner.transfer(address(this).balance);
}


function SetReceiver(address payable _fund) public onlyOwner {
    fundreceiver = _fund;
}


function SetPreSellingStatus() public onlyOwner {
    if (is_preselling) {
        is_preselling = false;
    } else {
        is_preselling = true;
    }
}
```

}

```
 }
```